# trying to work in R

Tags: r, variables

can anyone help me starting using R. 
For example, I would like to change numbers of 1+2+3+4+5 with any other, likewise, I would like to write a+b+c+d+e, where any of these letter could be changed by any number. 
So, can anyone tell me how to start?

Thanks

Comment: At first, I want to thank you for your answer. Then, I would like to ask you where I put something wrong. Actually, these are all of the combinations I tryed, but somewhere I am mistaking. And I do not know where. Besides, I have written everything into the same line (as I am weiting here), to prevent error (from similar reasons). But they certainly occured affter the fist several characters.

Comment: > -funcion(a, b, c, d, e) {a+B+C+d+e}
Error: unexpected '{' in "-funcion(a, b, c, d, e) {"

Comment: > <-function(a, b, c, d, e) {A+B+C+D+E} A=1 B=2 C=3 D=4 E=5 add (A, B, C, D, E)
Error: unexpected assignment in "<-"

Answer (score 2):

You definitely need to study by yourself, if I may suggest. Just google "R tutorial" or the like to find online resources.

In the meantime, have a look below:

```
#(Very) minimalistic example function
add <- function(a, b, c, d, e) {
    a + b + c + d + e
}

# Define variables you want to add up
A = 1
B = 2
C = 3
D = 4
E = 5

# Use the add() function defined above
# with the variables just defined as arguments
add(A, B, C, D, E)
# [1] 15

# Now change A and E values
A = 4
E = 6

# Use the add() function with new A and E
add(A, B, C, D, E)
# [1] 19
```

Comment: Actually, I sent you only the first and the last of my attempts, because everything is similar and has no use of sending them separately. But I know that I am making mistake somewhere in typing, just I do not know where